# Arrays, pointers, and memory management toy example question in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I was playing around with C memory and pointers, and I had some questions:

```c
int* foo(){
  int a[100] = ...;
  int* b = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
  ... do something ... 
  return b
}
```

- Is the memory consumed by `a` freed immediately after exiting the function?
- Would changing the definition to `int b [100];` be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
int a[100] = ...;
```

declares a local object with the automatic storage duration. So after exiting the function the array will not be alive and its memory can be used for other purposes.

Returning from the function the array

```
int b [100];
```

like

```
return b;
```

makes the returned pointer invalid because as it has been said above the array b will not be alive after exiting the function

As for the dynamically allocated memory

```
int* b = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

then it will be freed only when you will implicitly call the function `free` or when the process will stop its execution.

You could return the array if it had static storage duration. For example

```
static int b[100];
```

Comment: Right, so to explicitly answer my question, I _cannot_ change `int* b = malloc` to `int b[]`, correct?

Comment: It should result in a segmentation fault, I think

Comment: @AlexColeman A segmentation fault can occur if you will try to dereference the pointer to the returned array.

Comment: @AlexColeman You could return the array if it had static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `a` is scoped to the function and as soon as the function exits it *falls out of scope* meaning any references to it, like pointers, are invalidated. Understanding scope is really important, so be sure to learn more about this before you end up introducing undefined behaviour into your programs inadvertently.

Changing `b` to be the same as `a` would subject it to the same problems. `malloc()` is used to dynamically allocate something and it will be valid *until explicitly released* with `free()`.

Don't forget that allocating memory comes with the responsibility of releasing it. You need to have a plan to deal with that allocation.